# Make uneven table layout

Tags: html, asp.net

When I use `<table>` with `<tr>` and `<td>` I always get `NxN` tables and not what I want.

For example:

```
<table border = "1">
<tr> <td> Do you love peanuts? This is a very important question. </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Yes, I do. </td> <td> No, I don't. </td> </tr>
</table>
```

And yet, it looks like a 2x2 as one there is a blank square created over the page.

An example is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un6eq.png).

How can I make the first row (with the one element) spread the same as the one with two elements. I'm not talking about minimizing number of lines (in the text) or whatever, I mean just stretching it up to there.

Comment: Use attribute `colspan="2"` on the first td. Check this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: @Yasel - Post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using the attribute colspan on the td tag:

```html
<table border = "1">
 <tr> 
  <td colspan="2">
   Do you love peanuts? This is a very important question.
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   Yes, I do.
  </td>
  <td>
   No, I don't. 
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr> 
   <td>
    <table border="1">
     <tr>
      <td width="250px">Do you love peanuts? This is a very important question.</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table border="1">
     <tr>
      <td width="250px">
       Yes, I do.
      </td>
      <td>
       No, I don't. 
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```